# svd in python and R

Tags: python, r, numpy

I have a matrix x of dimension 2000 * 12000 .  When I run svd in R  it takes few minutes but than I have the result.

Instead in python using `numpy.linalg.svd(x,False)` I have waited for different minutes and I am still waiting the result.

Is there some sort of bug in svd in python?

```
import scipy.io
import os
import numpy as np
data = scipy.io.loadmat("RawData.mat")
x=np.column_stack((data['K'],data['S'],data['M'],data['U'],data['V'],data['L']))
svd=np.linalg.svd(x,False)
```

I am starting to think that the  problem is the size of the matrix. Is there a limit for numpy matrix ?

```
>>> x=np.ndarray(shape=(2000,12000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Comment: Try it on smaller matrices first to make sure _you_ haven't made an error in your code somewhere upstream.

Comment: I used svd different time in python. My code is only 1-read the matrix 2-run svd.   I will post all my code

Comment: Why is this labeled `scikit-learn` if you're using NumPy's SVD implementation? Anyway, try the one in `scipy.linalg`, it might be faster.

Comment: Ok the problem was the memory. I was using 32bit python. now with 64bit version it works well